# What is kufr without intention

Tags: kufr

Assalamualaikum , I have heard that kufr or disbelief happens through actions, words or beliefs and he will be a kafir if he do the following things and there is no priority whether he wanted to leave Islam or not
My question is what is actually meant by unintentional and intentional kufr how it happens can you briefly tell the difference and rulling
I done an act of kufr , at that time I had a thought not to do so I don't pay attention to the thought as I thought it was waswas happened to me  and I done the act but later found it is kufr , does I will be out of islam
Please answer
Anybody please answer please read my comment too to see my situation please answer

Comment: I think you should elaborate more on the question. There are holes in your question.

Comment: @ Sohan Arafat can you please tell it is kufr or not please read my comment below I am scared

Comment: Stop scaring. Just thinking about something doesn't make you kafir.Let me take a look at this.

Comment: @ Sohan arafat Please tell it is kufr or not , let allah give you a happy life

Comment: Kufr requires intention to be referred to as such.

Comment: @ medi 1 saif , it was long before I don't remember correctly , I know I had a thought at that time that it is kufr doing so.. but I didn't pay attention to the thought I felt it is waswas and allah will not punish for doing so , hence we have to avoid this thoughts to get rid of waswases so I laid to my bed , I know never in my life I would intend so

Comment: Please refrain from changing your question into an entirely different question. It's an inappropriate use of the edit tool and especially rude after people have already taken the time to answer the original.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes shaitan gives us waswasah and bad thought about Allah to make us feel like we are doing kufr, this is uninetional kufr and we have little controll over it so it should be ignored.

Comment: @ anonymous muslim doing an act of kufr when your affected by waswas is called as unintentional kufr ?

Comment: I am just saying that alot of people say that they get bad thoughts about Allah and think that those bad thoughts count as shirk, which is not the case. I don't understand your situation that well please elaborate

Comment: last year when I was going to sleep , there was a  low lying closedcupbord near the leg possition in the bed as bed is little higher I take up my feet against the cupboard that has Islamic books I had the knowledge of books in my mind but I thought it was waswas happening so I didn't pay attention to the thought and thought to avoid this bad waswases I have to ignore the thoughts , later I found doing like this is kufr please tell what I done is kufr or not

Comment: I understand you situation now, and actually I beleive I have seen this exact description somewhere else on this website, anyways, you have not done kufr, you simply did not know that what you were doing was wrong and after you found out it was kufr, you came and asked a question on this website, that shows that you care and are concerned and have good intentions, do not worry you are not in the wrong, try to be more careful after this

Comment: @ anonymous muslim , I had a thought that doing like this is kufr and allah will punish you but as a victim of waswas for years I thought it is also a waswas and allah will not hold me accountable for this , I thought if we have to get rid of such waswases  we have to avoid these thoughts, please tell it is kufr

Comment: sorry for such a late reply, to answer your question, no this is not kufr, you are a good muslim and shaytaan is trying to put bad thoughts in your mind to mess with you, dont pay attention to these thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

Walaikum-Assalam,
Your question is very unclear. But let me try. I think you are suffering from a guilt of doing something that is not acceptable in Islam. But I think something you are unaware of can't be accused. So I think it is not kufr. Just pray to Allah for forgiveness and stay calm. About 7-8 years ago I tried to practice black magic from internet(Nothing worked of course). But then I noticed that this was not good thing, and it is very specifically forbidden in Islam ,even if you want to use it for good. So I stopped and started to practice religion. I hope you can find a way too.

Comment: @ Sohan Arafat , I am having doubt whether I done is kufr or not , it was an year before so I don't remember the incident clearly with some identifications I had I asked to sheikh Assim Al hakeem , he told it is not kufr even then I am very much scared I asked forgiveness to allah and recited shahada but then 2 I am scared and I can't sleep or eat or smile